# Cannot disable button if DataGrid have no items

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want disable a button if the `DataGrid` have no items, so I did:

```
<Button>
 <Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Count, ElementName=myDataGrid}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
 </Button.Style>
</Button
```

the button is even enable, what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datagrid doesn't have a count property, but it's itemssource does.

```
    <Button Content="Count">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myDataGrid
, Path=ItemsSource.Count}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```